# How to efficiently use PyMongo cursor

Tags: python, performance, pymongo, database-cursor

Please propose ways to access data returned from `collections.find()` in an efficient manner.

Is a `for` iteration the recommended way?
How do I keep the character of a cursor being an `Iterable`?

Thx

Comment: What aspect of it is inefficient?

Comment: Wasn't there an answer to the question already that has magically disappered?

Comment: @BellyBuster: Nothing specific. Just avoid pitfalls and prevent common mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly:

A cursor implements methods of `Iterable` and `Iterator` (after diving into the code of PyMongo's `cursor.py`). Thus, all the usual care working with iterators has to be taken.